# Java GDAL Bindings: Write Out VRT File

Tags: gdal, java, vrt

I would like to use Java GDAL bindings to subset a GeoTIFF and write the result in VRT format.

I have found several old posts, one of them states that this functionality is yet to be implemented in Java GDAL bindings:

- http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2014-June/039337.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25522833/how-to-write-a-output-file-in-java-using-gdal-library

What is the situation in 2017?

Did anyone try to save VRT from Java using GDAL bindings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save a Dataset as a VRT file. 
Create a VRT driver object, and then copy your custom dataSet into a new Dataset in the following manner:

```
// dataSet is the subset Dataset object you have created from the orginal GeoTIFF
Driver vrtDriver = GetDriverByName("VRT");
Dataset vrtDataSet = vrtDriver.CreateCopy("sample.vrt", dataSet);
```

This will create a VRT file called sample.vrt in your working directory. The assumption is that you have already registered your GDAL bindings.

Comment: Thanks, I have already discovered this way. Nevertheless, accepting your answer

Comment: and giving you +1